# Unable to display content behind navbar when fixed position

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, sass

I have a simple react app which displays my navbar, but whenever i do its position fixed; it stays at top but the content does not hide behind.
My navbar:

```
class Nav extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            <header className="toolbar">
                <nav className="toolbar__navigation">
                    <div className="toolbar__toggle-button">
                    <DrawerButton drawer={this.props.drawer} click={this.props.drawerClickHandler} />
                    </div>
                    <img className="Nav__Logo-A" src={Mylogo} alt=""/>
                    <div className="toolbar__logo"><a href="/">Akcosh</a></div>
                    <div className="spacer"></div>
                    <div className="toolbar_navigation-items">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="/">Software</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/">About</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/">Profile</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </header>
            </div>

        )
    }
}
```

my css:

```
.toolbar{
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #212121;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 45px;
}

.toolbar__logo{
    margin-left: 1rem;
}

.toolbar__navigation {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0 1rem;
}

.toolbar__logo a{
    color: #282828;;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.spacer{
    flex: 1;
}

.toolbar_navigation-items ul{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
}

.toolbar_navigation-items li{
    padding: 0 0.5rem;
}

.toolbar_navigation-items a{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.toolbar_navigation-items a:hover,
.toolbar_navigation-items a:active{
    color: aqua;
}

@media(max-width: 768px){
    .toolbar_navigation-items{
        display: none;
    }
    .toolbar{
        height: 68px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #aca4a4;
        background-color: #e5e3e30a;
    }
    .toolbar__logo a{
        font-family: Roboto,Helvetica,sans-serif;
        letter-spacing: 1.6px;
        font-size: 20px;
        margin-left: 5px;
        font-weight: 400;
    }
    .Nav__Logo-A{
        animation-name: out;
        position: absolute;
        height: 210%;
        width:100%;
        left: -36%;
        margin-top: 9px;
        transition: .4s all;
    }
    .Nav__Logo-A:hover{
        cursor: default;
        transform: rotate(360deg);
        left: -36%;
        margin-top: 10px;

    }

}

}
```

I have tried everything but nothing is working; i want my navbar fixed on top and content behind it, if i have some other component below the Nav component, i want its content/text to go behind nav because it is fixed at top

Comment: Set the padding or margin for the content other than your navbar.

Answer (score 0):

try to modify the z-index so it can stay on top

```css
.toolbar{
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #212121;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 45px;
    z-index:2; // or some bigger value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try is setting the z indexes!

```
.toolbar{
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #212121;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 45px;
    z-index:99;

}
```

And then after that, if your content is still displaying in front of the navbar, go into that items CSS class and add

```
.exampleClass {
 z-index:-1;
```

}